# Bootstrap 4 carousel not responsive images

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, responsive-images

Look at this:
http://www.consultacultura.it/portale_comunale_della_cultura.asp?IDcomune=1

Carousel images are not responsive like images under of it. They have the same class img-fluid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6...

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21611

As a ***workaround*** you can use..

```
.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: block;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/0QUU06MiIL

Comment: I correct myself ... the problem is with chrome only the other browser are ok. 
About display:block; it make the image responsive but corrupt the slideshow (all images are show at the same time)

Comment: It should only be applied to the active item as described. http://www.codeply.com/go/0QUU06MiIL

Comment: Thank you, also with style="width:100%; height:100%" as described in issue 21611 from github works correctly.
To be my first time on stackoverflow i'm very satisfied!

Answer (score 2):

For me that workaround did not work for both, desktops and mobiles. I adjusted the proposed workaround a bit to make it -orientation- sensible.

```
@media (orientation: portrait) { 
    .carousel-item.active,
    .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-item-prev {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
}

@media (orientation: landscape) { 
    .carousel-item.active,
    .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-item-prev {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:96vh;
    }
}
```